# create costum listbox in middle of page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to create page like photo1 with listbox in middle of page and need header for listbox:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWHYt.jpg)

my flutter code is like here:

```
Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: ListView(children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 40,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                    child: Text('Categoria del Prodotto'),
                  )
                ])),
Expanded(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<CategoriaData>>(
        future: _db.getCategories(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final List<CategoriaData>? categories = snapshot.data;

          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          }

          if (categories != null || categories!.isNotEmpty) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final catinstance = categories[index];

                  return ListTile(
                    title: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15, top: 10),
                      child: Text(catinstance.nomecategoria),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }

          return const Text('No Data Found.');
        },
      ),
    );
```

but always i see this output like photo2 that i dont like it,how could i fix page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQvAo.jpg)

just fix flutter code to view page output correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Expanded` and `ListView` from `Categoria del Prodotto`, leave it just as `Container`:

```
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.grey.shade500,
              child: Text('Categoria del Prodotto'),
            )
```